# Can't edit R location for R shiny-server

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

Working on ubuntu v 16xx, got the Shiny-server running decently after stumbling through the docs. I need to change Shiny-server's R version to 3.4, located at home/ubuntu/R/R-3.4.0 .

http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#r-installation-location
in 1.3.5 R Installation Location:

It says to edit  /etc/init.d/shiny-server or /etc/init/shiny-server.conf, but neither of location or file even exists. It also says you can add an environment variable  but then only lists locations for upstart (which is outdated) and the init.d (which doesnt exist).

Comment: My configuration file exists at "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf". Is it there?

Comment: What does `locate shiny-server.conf` (on the bash prompt) reveal? If it's a debian/ubuntu package, what about `dpkg -S shiny-server.conf`? This seems to be a unix problem and not one about programming, R, or shiny.

Comment: There's no setting in the shiny-server.conf that controls version. I started over, only installing R 3.4, but shiny server can't find it apparently.